# What does ._value do and where does it come from in React Native PanResponder?

Tags: javascript, react-native

[React Native documents](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) give an example using PanResponder where a property is set using "._value".

What does "._value" do?

```
    const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

    const panResponder = useRef(
      PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: () => {
          pan.setOffset({
            x: pan.x._value, // What do you do?
            y: pan.y._value // You too!
          });
        },
        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
          [
            null,
            {
              dx: pan.x,
              dy: pan.y
            }
          ]
        ),
        onPanResponderRelease: () => {
          pan.flattenOffset();
        }
      })
    ).current;
```

Comment: Without using _value it gives you an error " "translateX" must be a number". Looking at it, I am thinking it converts a decimal to a number.